# Hospedagem de serviço WCF com criação de endpoints?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, restful

Observei que ao executar um projeto do tipo Rest quando aberto a interface, abre o browser da internet é lista todo o conteúdo da pasta, sendo necessário selecionar o “.svc” quando executado o “.svc” e aberto uma tela de WCF Test Client, existe alguma configuração para abri no endereço correto? O meu “web.config “ esta desta forma:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>


  <system.serviceModel>

    <!--Adicionado -->
    <services>
      <service name="WcfRest.BookService">

        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfRest.IBookService"  behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior" >
        </endpoint>

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:3951/WcfRest/BookService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>


      </service>  
    </services>

    <!--Adicionado --> 

    <behaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <!--Adicionado -->

      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>


  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SERRESTEEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=SERRESTE;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=**;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O "endereço correto" é exatamente o que termina com ".svc". O que você quer exatamente?

Comment: Amigo, na minha pergunta eu falo o que estou precisando, agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O WCFTestClient não funciona para acessar serviços WCF REST. Quando você aponta o WCFTestClient para um serviço, ele tenta acessar o *metadata endpoint* do serviço, que descreve todas as operações, e o *binding* que precisa ser usado para acessá-lo. Os formatos de metadata suportado pelo WCF (WSDL e WS-Metadata) são usados para descrever serviços SOAP, e não REST, então o *test client* não irá conseguir consumir o seu serviço REST, já que ele não sabe como fazê-lo.

Note que pode até ser que alguma operação funcione - se você pede a um serviço WCF pela sua metadata, ele vai fazer um "melhor esforço" para responder. Mas de modo geral, as operações não conseguem ser acessadas pelo *test client*.

Se quiser saber mais, o post em [Mixing Add Service Reference and WCF Web HTTP (a.k.a. REST) endpoint does not work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlosfigueira/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work) descreve com mais detalhes o que eu mencionei acima.

Comment: Amigo, todas as operações estão funcionando, a minha dúvida talvez não tenha ficado claro, mais é sobre a execução, quando é feito a execução do serviço ele abre de uma forma diferente, como visto nas imagens, se executado na interface abre o browser da internet e lista todos os arquivos da pasta.

Comment: Se executado do “.svc” abre uma de WCF Test Client, por isso eu postei o web.config, quero saber o que preciso configurar para o serviço abri a página correta.

Comment: Para abrir quando você faz "F5" no Visual Studio? Se for isso, vá nas propriedades do seu projeto, selecione "Current Page" (estou com a versão em inglês), e selectione a página que você quer abrir (BookService.svc).

Comment: Acho que era isso! vou testar!